# Vue: weird behavior of :to property on @click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this object:

**Hashtag.vue**:

```
<template>
  <router-link :to="getTo"
               custom v-slot="{ navigate }">
  <div role="link" @click="navigate">
    {{text}}</div>
  </router-link>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    text: {
      type: String
    },
    date:  {
      type: String
    },
    link: {
      type: String,

    }
  },
  created()  {
    console.log("this link: " + this.link);
  },
  computed:  {
    getTo: function()  {
      console.log("text: " + this.text);
      console.log("link: " + "hashtag/" + this.text);
      return "hashtag/" + this.text;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And use it in **HashtagsList.vue**:

```
<template>
  <div>

    <Hashtag text="test1"/>
    <Hashtag text="test2"/>
    <Hashtag text="test3"/>
    <Hashtag text="test4"/>
    <Hashtag text="test5"/>

  </div>
</template>
```

However when I click a hashtag when located at

```
http://localhost:8080/hashtag/sometag
```

it goes to

```
http://localhost:8080/hashtag/hashtag/sometag
```

Instead of

```
http://localhost:8080/hashtag/sometag
```

How do I fix it?

```
http://localhost:8080/hashtag/test2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using "/" in front of your route to make it absolute and vue will not concate that route.

```
"/hastag/" + this.text
```